# AttributeError: module 'redis' has no attribute 'RedisCluster'

Tags: python, redis, redis-cluster, redisclient

I'm trying the connect to a redis cluster with the below code.

```py
import redis

ssl_ca_certs='<path_to_ca_certfile>'

r = redis.RedisCluster(
  host='<RedisHOST>',
  port=6379,
  ssl=True,
  password='<password>',
  ssl_ca_certs=ssl_ca_certs
  )
```

The code was working fine for some time. but recently I'm getting error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/rnatarajan/network-signals/py-demo/get-redis-cli.py", line 7, in
>
> r = redis.RedisCluster(
>
> AttributeError: module 'redis' has no attribute 'RedisCluster'

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the redis package.

I uninstalled `redis-py-cluster` package.

Note: I'm using ubuntu 22.04

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I'm using python 3.10

```bash
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.12
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Do you by any chance, have another file named `redis.py`, in the same directory of your project?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be used like this:

```
    redis.cluster.RedisCluster(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

redis-py (`pip install redis`) now supports clustering so you shouldn't need an additional package.  Try something like this:

```py
from redis.cluster import RedisCluster as Redis
rc = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
print(rc.get_nodes())
    [[host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,name=127.0.0.1:6379,server_type=primary,redis_connection=Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,db=0>>>], [host=127.0.0.1,port=6378,name=127.0.0.1:6378,server_type=primary,redis_connection=Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6378,db=0>>>], [host=127.0.0.1,port=6377,name=127.0.0.1:6377,server_type=replica,redis_connection=Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6377,db=0>>>]]
```

Reference: https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/clustering.html#